# Classification Algorithms

Tags: r, classification, image-processing

Rather than due a google search and hope to find "the best" or an exhaustive list of classification algorithms I thought it might be easier to pose my questions here, and then get advice from you guys.

**The Problem**: I have a multiple black and white images of animals (say for example of a household cat, tiger and lion) and want to be able to build an automated algorithm for classifying the images as either being a cat, tiger or lion.  I have several pictures to train the algorithm on, and then I want to  be able to classify future photos.

**The Question**:  What classification algorithms exists that are best suited for this type of problem? I stress the fact that the images are black and white so there is no RGB color mapping that seems useful (maybe I am wrong about this?).

**The Answers:** I'm looking for key words or references to papers, but particularly useful if the method mentioned has been built into a package in `R`.

Answer (score 1):

There (at least) two schools of thought on this.

The individual pixel values do not carry much---if any---information about the image content. Instead, much of the information seems to be carried by interactions among the pixels. If you can do some **feature engineering** to generate features that capture these interactions, these features can then be fed to a support vector machine, decision tree, or other standard classification algorithm. The "best" features probably vary with the application, but you might want to consider:

- SIFT: Scale-Invariant Image Features (e.g., [Lowe, 1999](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=790410))
- HOG: Histograms of Oriented Gradients (e.g.,  [Dalal and Triggs, 2005](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf))

The goal here is to generate features that are not sensitive to moderate amounts of translation, rotation, or scaling. For some problems, you may also know that some features (e.g., straight lines for OCR) carry valuable information.

An alternative approach is to learn these features directly from the training data, using something like an **autoencoder**. This is particularly common in **deep learning** models and you may want to look at the work of Yann LeCun, Geoff Hinton, and Yoshua Bengio, among others. These features are typically fed directly into a neural network. These networks' structures usually help capture the relationship between nearby pixels, as in a **convolutional neural network** but you could presumably use the autoencoders' outputs for other types of classifiers (e.g., SVMs) too.

Answer (score 0):

SVM, classification trees are two of the more easily accessible methods which immediately come to mind. They both have a large amount of R implementation as well as some fairly well done introductions floating around places such as Kaggle.